# Reactive conditional throttling operator

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm looking for an operator like [Throttle](https://rxmarbles.com/#throttle), except the throttling behavior is only applied when a boolean value is true. So given two observables `IObservable<T> values` and `IObservable<bool> throttleCondition`, I want to create an observable that does the following:

- All values from `values` are passed through, until
- when `throttleCondition` produces `true`. Then no values are passed through until,
- when `throttleCondition` produces `false` again. Then the last value of the sequence is propagated and any new values are passed through again.

Or, expressed in a marble diagram (notice the 4):

```
           values |   0 1   2 3 4   5 6
throttleCondition | F     T       F
           result |   0 1         4 5 6
```

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> self, IObservable<bool> throttleCondition)
{
    bool cond = false;
    throttleCondition.Subscribe(v => cond = v);
    return self.Window(throttleCondition).Select(obs => cond ? obs.TakeLast(1) : obs).SelectMany(obs => obs);
}
```

But this isn't threadsafe as there could be a race between the Select and the Subscribe.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Maybe there is already an operator for this that I am not seeing?

EDIT:
Here is a unit test for the function I need:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestThrottleWhen()
{
    //Setup
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    Subject<int> numberValues = new Subject<int>();
    Subject<bool> flagValues = new Subject<bool>();

    //Define actions
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1), () => flagValues.OnNext(false));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(10), () => numberValues.OnNext(0));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(20), () => numberValues.OnNext(1));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(30), () => flagValues.OnNext(true));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(40), () => numberValues.OnNext(2));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(50), () => numberValues.OnNext(3));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(60), () => numberValues.OnNext(4));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(70), () => flagValues.OnNext(false));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(71), () => flagValues.OnNext(true));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(72), () => flagValues.OnNext(false));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(80), () => numberValues.OnNext(5));
    scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromTicks(90), () => numberValues.OnNext(6));
    var actual = scheduler.Start(() => numberValues.ThrottleWhen(flagValues), 0, 0, 100);

    //Assert
    var expected = new[]
    {
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(10, 0),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(20, 1),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(70, 4),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(80, 5),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(90, 6)

    };
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expected, actual.Messages);
}
```

EDIT 2:
I ended up using a modified version of Alex' answer:

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> self, IObservable<bool> throttleCondition)
{
    var isPaused = throttleCondition.Prepend(false).DistinctUntilChanged();
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        object lockObj = new object();
        bool gateIsOpen = false;
        return Observable.CombineLatest(
                self.Synchronize(lockObj).Do(_ => gateIsOpen = true),
                isPaused.Synchronize(lockObj).Do(paused => gateIsOpen = !paused && gateIsOpen),
                (number, paused) => (number, paused)
            )
            .Where(tuple => !tuple.paused && gateIsOpen)
            .Select(tuple => tuple.number);
    });
}
```

Comment: You need something like this: `flagValues.Select(x => x ? Observable.Never<int>() : numberValues).Switch()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity That wouldn't produce number 4 in my example. I need the last value produced during the period in which the boolean was true (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be the final attempt... ^^

Coming back to the *CombineLatest* approach and combining a bit of your solution, I came up with an additional flag that will help us avoid the corner case where the flag is changing back and forth without the any values emitting from the values observable.

```
bool numberChangedFlag = false;

_numberValues
    .Do(_ => numberChangedFlag = true)
    .CombineLatest(_flagValues.Do(x => numberChangedFlag = !x && numberChangedFlag), (number, flag) => (number, flag))
    .Where(tuple => !tuple.flag && numberChangedFlag)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.number)
    .Subscribe(DoYourMagic);
```

I've tried it with your tests and it looks like it works.

Although I don't like the fact that we need a local helper variable to solve this, going deeper and creating a helper observable seems like something that will make the code over complicated.

Let me know if this time it works. :)

Comment: Close, but not what I need. :) Your solution will skip the last value in the throttled sequence (number 4 in my example), which is what I want to keep.

Comment: You are right. I'm not sure how I missed this part.
I'm updating the answer, with a completely different approach,
I'll update later my original answer to fix the issue, so you'll have two options to choose from. :)

Comment: The new approach does indeed reproduce the last value now. However, if the flag is toggled to true and back to false with no values emitted, it produces the value 4 again which is unexpected. I've updated the unit test to demonstrate this.

Comment: Also, it seems all items up to the first flag=true are not passed through?

Comment: I appreciate the work you are putting into this, but your previous answer was actually closer. Your new suggestion misses number 4 again. Also the unit test first creates a subscription, and then runs the OnNext commands in order of appearance (notice the "Schedule"). Therefore, its impossible for the operators to miss any of the values. The values are emitted after the subscription.

Comment: Ok, so now it doesn't miss 4 anymore, but it produces a duplicate 4 after the toggling of the flag again.

Comment: I added another corner case just in case, which is sending the number 4 again just before sending 5. I tried using the DistinctUntilChanged operator and the corner case above helped me see that it doesn't work. ^^

Comment: Alright, so it seems to be working now. I added a prepend of false to the throttle so values pass through by default. I also added a DistinctUntilChanged so if the throttle is set twice to the same boolean, values are not duplicated. I then added a lock to synchronize the access to the flag. Finally, I added a Defer as multiple subscriptions accessing the same flag and lock could have unexpected side-effects. If there are any bugs left, I'm not seeing them. Thanks

Comment: @AlexPshul - You shouldn't have local variables like that - wrap them in a `Defer` or `Create` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is cleaner, but clean is in the eye of the beholder:

At core, the solution looks like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleWhenCore<T>(this IObservable<T> self, IObservable<bool> throttleCondition)
{

    return throttleCondition
        .StartWith(false)
        .Join(self,
            b => b ? Observable.Empty<bool>() : throttleCondition,
            t => self,
            (b, t) => (b, t)
        )
        .Where(tuple => !tuple.b)
        .Select(tuple => tuple.t);
}
```

`Join` is not well understood: For each item introduced from the left observable (`throttle
Condition` here) opens a left window. Each item introduced from the right observable (`self`) opens a right window. Whenever a left window intersects in time with a right window, produce a new value.

Naturally, you can choose when to close windows: In our case, any item from `self` closes the latest right window, so after the first item, there's always one and only one right window open at any time. For the `throttleCondition` left side, when the value is false, the window stays open (allowing all values when F is up) to go through. When `throttleCondition` is true, then we open and immediately close the window, which only allows the most recent value to go through.

This passes all your tests cases except for the case where you open and close the throttle. In that case it double emits 4 at the 72 tick mark. To fix that, you add in an indexer and a `DistinctUntilChanged`:

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> self, IObservable<bool> throttleCondition)
{

    return throttleCondition
        .StartWith(false)
        .Join(self.Select((item, index) => (item, index)),
            b => b ? Observable.Empty<bool>() : throttleCondition,
            t => self,
            (b, t) => (b, t)
        )
        .Select(tuple => tuple.t)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(tuple => tuple.item);
}
```

If you need more explanation, let me know. I much prefer this over locking/state variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, building off @Enigmativity's comment. Best way to think about this is to separate this into two problems: Getting the latest when condition turns true, and emitting freely when the condition is false, then merge the two together.

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> self, IObservable<bool> throttleCondition)
{

    return throttleCondition.Publish(_throttleCondition => self.Publish(_self => Observable.Merge(
        _throttleCondition   //Get latest when true handler
            .Where(b => !b)
            .WithLatestFrom(
                _self.Select((item, index) => (item, index)),
                (_, t) => t
            )
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Select(t => t.item),

        _throttleCondition   //Freely emit when false, default start with false.
            .StartWith(false)
            .Select(b => b ? Observable.Empty<T>(): _self)
            .Switch()

    )));
}
```

This uses the same indexer trick as my other answer to prevent duplicates.